# Testing independence and setting constraint matrices in a multinomial logit model in R

Tags: logistic, anova, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio, multinomial-logit

I have a data set the looks like this (called rand_df as this is a random subset from the much larger dataframe):

```
structure(list(motive = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Build skill", 
"Enjoy Nature", "Fish to eat", "Other", "Relaxation", "Socialize"
), class = "factor"), survey = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("random", 
"web", "public"), class = "factor")), out.attrs = list(dim = c(motive = 6L, 
survey = 3L), dimnames = list(motive = c("motive=Build skill", 
"motive=Enjoy Nature", "motive=Fish to eat", "motive=Other", 
"motive=Relaxation", "motive=Socialize"), survey = c("survey=random", 
"survey=web", "survey=public"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")


         motive survey
1  Enjoy Nature public
2         Other public
3    Relaxation    web
4   Fish to eat random
5    Relaxation public
6   Fish to eat public
7   Fish to eat random
8   Fish to eat    web
9  Enjoy Nature random
10  Build skill public
11   Relaxation public
12   Relaxation random
13 Enjoy Nature public
14  Build skill    web
15   Relaxation    web
16    Socialize random
17  Fish to eat random
18   Relaxation    web
19  Fish to eat    web
20   Relaxation random
```

I am trying to build a logit model so that I can test whether the survey mode plays a significant role in determining a respondent's motive. Originally I had build a standard logit model with a glm like this:

```
fit<-glm(motive~survey, family=binomial, data=rand_df)
```

and followed this with a chi-square test of independence to determine the significance of the survey mode like this to test against the null model:

```
anova(fit, test = "Chisq") 


        Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)
NULL                      19     13.003         
survey  2    1.855        17     11.148   0.3956
```

After a little research I have realized that I need to be using a multinomial logit model since my response variable is not binary and have explored doing this same test with the vglm() call in the library VGAM using the following:

```
library(VGAM)
fit <- vglm(motive~survey, multinomial, data=rand_df)
anova(fit)

       Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)
survey 10   10.008        95     61.721   0.4398
```

I am wondering if I can interpret this output (which is from a likelihood ratio test) the same way as I was interpreting the chi-square test against the null model with the logit framework or if I need to set up the anova(fit) call differently?

Also, I have noticed that when I alter the constraint matrices within the logit model (`multinomial(parallel=T)`) that my significance is greatly altered. How do I determine whether I need to set my constraint matrices equal or unequal?

Comment: If you only want to test whether the survey mode is independent of the motive outcome, why not just run a traditional chi-square test? (i.e. using `chisq.test()` on your data in contingency table format). Is there any further purpose to fitting a multinomial logit model for you? Also, setting `multinomial(parallel=T)`  in `vglm` eliminates motive-specific intercepts and fixed effects - this is akin to saying the regression equation for all motive outcomes is the same, relative to the reference outcome. It's hard to say whether this constraint is plausible or of any interest to your question.

Comment: I tried this initially but the reason I am not using a traditional chi-square is that my sample sizes are pretty variable (650 public vs 1400 web vs 1100 random) and my understanding is that these differing sample sizes are going to affect the significance within a traditional chi-square. Am I interpreting that incorrectly? Thanks for that description of the constraint matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @awhug notes, you are unlikely to gain much over the standard cross-tabulation-based $\chi^2$ test with your data that approach seems like it is the best path forward given your stated goals of assessing independence of these two factors.

In fact, the multinomial logit model with a single predictor can *essentially* reproduce the results of the cross-tabulation-based $\chi^2$ test with its predicted values.  Take for example the implementation of a multinomial logit in the `{nnet}` package as applied to your data:

```
> nnet::multinom(motive ~ survey, data = rand_df) |> predict() |> chisq.test(y = rand_df$motive)
# weights:  24 (15 variable)
initial  value 35.835189 
iter  10 value 26.424566
iter  20 value 25.858751
iter  30 value 25.856454
final  value 25.856449 
converged

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  predict(nnet::multinom(motive ~ survey, data = rand_df)) and rand_df$motive
X-squared = 8.1066, df = 10, p-value = 0.6184
```

in this case, it so happens that the result perfectly matches the Pearson result when running the $\chi^2$ test using both factors:

```
>  vcd::assocstats(table(rand_df$motive, rand_df$survey))
                     X^2 df P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio 10.0083 10  0.43977
Pearson           8.1066 10  0.61843

Phi-Coefficient   : NA 
Contingency Coeff.: 0.537 
Cramer's V        : 0.45
```

Note also that the Likelihood Ratio version of the test (a [G test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test); thanks to @awhug for the suggestion), produces a slightly different result in terms of the p-value but leads to the same conclusion.  Moreover, the Likelihood Ratio $\chi^2$ produces an identical result to the result from the likelihood ratio tests from the model:

```
> anova(
  nnet::multinom(motive ~ survey, data = rand_df), 
  nnet::multinom(motive ~ 1, data = rand_df)
)
# weights:  24 (15 variable)
initial  value 35.835189 
iter  10 value 26.424566
iter  20 value 25.858751
iter  30 value 25.856454
final  value 25.856449 
converged
# weights:  12 (5 variable)
initial  value 35.835189 
final  value 30.860586 
converged
   Model Resid. df Resid. Dev   Test    Df LR stat.   Pr(Chi)
1      1        95   61.72117           NA       NA        NA
2 survey        85   51.71290 1 vs 2    10 10.00827 0.4397677
```

Again, the idea is that the much simpler cross-tabulation tests provided the same answer without needing to pull the data through a model.

In the end, the answer received from both cross-tabulation or model-based methods will be affected by differences in representation across *survey* categories; using a different test (or running the data through a model) won't change that imbalance.  The imbalance is a property of the data.

---

Note the results from `{VGAM}` match the `{nnet}` results in terms of fit to the data but do give different coefficients if you print the coefficients from each run.

Comment: Do you have a citation for the method of using the outcome and predicted outcomes from a multinomial logit model in a Pearson Chi-sq test? It neatly corresponds to the results of the survey/motivate Pearson Chi-sq test in this case, but I'm unsure where this method comes from and I can't seem to replicate it on other data. It also would probably be worth adding that the LR stat from the `anova` you run at the end is a [G test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test), which has a nice closed form solution and often closely corresponds to the Pearson's Chi-Square test.

Comment: @awhug, appreciate the comment.  The way my post is written is misleading as this is a specific case where they do happen to match and I don't note clearly enough that the "essentially reproduces the results" piece is key.  That is, there is not a general method to reproduce using predicted values through a multinomial logit - though I do seem to imply there is.  Will edit to clarify.

Comment: While I see the value of the chi-square test in the contingency table format and am clear that my results will be unchanged here, I am going to stick with the multinomial logit model as I am now planning to add some other independent variables (demographics, avidity, etc.) and I do not think I can run a traditional chi-square with those extra variables. But that is now beyond the scope of my initial question so thanks for this very thorough and helpful explanation. I really appreciate the insight.